# Solution to self-manage PHP-MySQL mailing list... premade solutions, classes, etc?

Tags: php, mysql, mailer

I was just wondering if people could throw out names of a few different mailing list scripts, classes, whatever, which will enable me to self-manage my own mailing list.

I currently use Aweber which is great and all, but I don't like relying on having my lists stored there, and more importantly, having to have people who purchase things from me or join a web service that I own have to opt-in using Aweber even though they've agreed to our T&C and agreed to receive emails from us.

I know there are other AR's that don't require double optin, but I'd rather just self host it and be able to do operations on the email list that I have stored, and take emails straight from the customer database as I need to.

*CLIFFNOTES*: Best self hosted PHP/MySQL email script/class/program/etc.?

I've seen PHPList suggested previously, but I've heard at least of 3-4 others that I can't seem to recall.

Comment: What did your own search turn out next to [PHPList](http://www.phplist.com/)?

Comment: It looks cool and all, but my main issue with it is the way it's laid out in the back end and ease of use for my VAs.  It looks like I'd have to custom code an interface to work with it, and I wish I could find a PHP mailer class instead to interface with my own custom written functions if I had to go that route

Comment: AFAIK it ships with `PHPMailer`. Anyway, which else apps did your search turned out with? If none, please search harder. And please list them here and what you reviewed so far, pros and cons and so on.

Comment: I also found ListMailPro, which is good for me, as it allows you to add conditional adds as far as if they join this list, then join them here, but I want something with functionality to call an add function.  Is PHPMailer a class?  If so, I'll research that and figure out what functionality it has and if it will interface with what I need.  What's their official project or repository?  I found a lot of stuff named "PHPMailer" and can't find the official site

Comment: Yes, [`PHPMailer`](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) is a class to send emails. It has quite some history and changed sites over time, it's current official location is: http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/ . Originally it was managed many years on sourceforge by the original maintainer.

Comment: Awesome, I'll research that, I'd select the answer if it works but it's just a comment, you should get your due credit for helping me... this community is great and I love being able to come and get answers for exactly what I need and humble myself, even though I feel knowledgable.  Thanks hakre and I'll come back and let you know how it's going!

Answer (score 0):

Although I prefer Wordpress over Joomla, the Acymailing solution is great and has worked successfully for several clients of mine: http://www.acyba.com/en/acymailing.html

Comment: Yeah, if I was more joomla interested then it would work great, but unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with Joomla nor want to take the time to learn it or port over my sites but I never even knew this existed.  Great plugin for those that want to use Joomla from the overview I gave it

Comment: The learning curve for Joomla is minimal, you could do a Joomla install and run this plugin standalone... then just write a php script that interfaces with the mysql db for subscriptions on any site, from my standpoint its less than an hour of coding, it would probably take more time to stylize the subscription form